# User cannot see attachments for one record but can see for other records on the same object

Tags: permissions, attachment, related-list

One user can see the attachments for 1 record but cannot see the attachments for another record for same object.

Scenario:
User : U
Object : A
Record 1: User U can see the attachments
Record 2: User U cannot see the attachments

Please advise. What can be the issue?

EDIT: Figured out the issue. The attachment is marked as Private. Any idea why by default attachment is marked private? Is there any way to restrict that?

Comment: `Attachments` or `Files`?

Comment: We are using Attachments

Comment: this sheds some light on it: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000pEl2QAE and https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=notes_fields.htm&type=5. What makes you think by default they are marked as private?